# Gaussian Elimination in C

Tags: c

This code works only if the system has unique solutions. When there is no solution or infinitely many solutions, it should print "Has no unique solution." but the code below prints "nan" or "inf". How can I do that?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i,j,k,n;
double A[20][20],c,x[10];
printf("\nEnter the size of matrix: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("\nEnter the elements of augmented matrix row-wise:\n");
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    for(j=1; j<=(n+1); j++)
    {
        printf(" A[%d][%d]:", i,j);
        scanf("%lf",&A[i][j]);
    }
}

for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
{
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(i!=j)
        {
            c=A[i][j]/A[j][j];
            for(k=1; k<=n+1; k++)
            {
                A[i][k]=A[i][k]-c*A[j][k];
            }
        }
    }
}
printf("\nThe solution is:\n");
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    x[i]=A[i][n+1]/A[i][i];
    printf("\n x%d=%0.3f\n",i,x[i]);
}
return(0);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to add checks for division by zero.

Comment: Certainly code is encountering division by 0.0 with `/A[j][j]` which occurs when there is a non-unique solution. `/0.0` also occurs due to rounding issues.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a check for the whether the number is valid or not before printing.If not valid, print your desired message.You can modify the last for loop in your code as follows:

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
 {
    x[i]=A[i][n+1]/A[i][i];
   //Nan and inf check
   if((A[i][i]!=A[i][i]) || (A[i][i] ==0))
      break;
   else
      printf("\n x%d=%0.3f\n",i,x[i]);
 }
 printf("Has no unique solution");
 return(0);
}
```

[Handling Infinity and Nan](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html)

Comment: This rather a comment than an answer.